# Consulta anidada PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Tengo una tabla empleado con la siguiente estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero obtener el jefe de cada empleado que esta identificado con la columna jefe.

Tengo la siguiente consulta anidada para obtener lo que busco, sin embargo no me retorna los nombres del jefe

```
select id_empleado, nombre, apellido, 
       (select (empleado.nombre ||' '|| empleado.apellido) as jefe_nombres 
        from empleado where id_empleado = jefe), jefe 
from empleado
```

Lo que quiero obtener es que en la columna jefe_nombres aparezca por ejemplo para el empleado con id 2 jefe_nombres = Pablo Ramiro Vallejo Zuñiga

**¿Cómo podría solucionar esto?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes realizar la subconsulta directamente en el select:

```
select id_empleado,
        nombre,
        apellido,
        jefe,
        (select b.nombre || ' ' || b.apellido from empleado b where b.id_empleado = a.jefe  ) as 'Nombre Jefe'
from empleado a
```

Este es el resultado (comprobado):

```
id_empleado nombre               apellido             jefe        Nombre Jefe                               
----------- -------------------- -------------------- ----------- ----------------------------------------- 
4           Pablo Ramiro         Vallejo Zuñiga       (NULL)      (NULL)                                    
9           Jorge Rafael         Almeida              4           Pablo Ramiro Vallejo Zuñiga               
2           Juan Guillermo       Pinzon               4           Pablo Ramiro Vallejo Zuñiga
```